# Fake/Local GCS service

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

My Java application uses GCS to download files. When I want to write tests for it, I should use a fake storage service. Before I test, a local GCS service can start or there should be fake client that will be replaced with real one.

How can I do that? I could not find except `"google-cloud-nio"`library.

Answer (score 3):

Bit late at the party but https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server should do it. 
You can find the docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/fsouza/fake-gcs-server)

Answer (score 0):

google-cloud-nio works well, though it doesn't claim to replicate all GCS features. Another option (if you don't mind it being less GCS-like) is to use jimfs.